# How to properly modify an array while iterating it

Tags: arrays, loops, crystal-lang

In Crystal, I want to change the Array I'm iterating over I do this:

```
strings = ["A","B","C"]

i = 0
strings.each do |string|
  strings[i] = string * 2
  i += 1
end
```

While it isn't the worst thing, I feel like there should be a more idiomatic way to achieve it, something like:

```
strings = ["A","B","C"]

strings.each do |string|
  string = string * 2
end
```

Is there anything like this possible in Chrystal?
Preferably something removing the need for an additional variable such as `i` in this case.
If so, is it considered a good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`Array#map!`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/Array.html#map!(&)-instance-method)

In this case `strings.map! {|string| string*2}` does exactly the same.